# curl command get nothing at expressjs hello-world-example

Tags: express, curl

I run the hellow-world-example of `expressjs`, then I tryed to use command `curl http://localhost:3000/` to see the result. But I got nothing.

The example:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Nothing returns in command line.
[image]

But It works fine in my browser.
[image]

So, Is there anything wrong?

Comment: What does `curl -v http://localhost:3000/` show?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Updated the screenshot.